# Cannot locate launch node of type + Can't locate node

Tags: ros, roslaunch, turtlebot, node, coordinates

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to create a node using [this code](http://answers.ros.org/question/67206/getting-accurate-real-time-xy-coordinates-with-gmapping/) in order to obtain the turtlebot coordinates in the map reference frame.

I've tried adding the node in an existing package, but I wasn't successful.

Therefore, I've created a new package (following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage), [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages) and [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorials). In the last tutorial, instead of using the publisher and subscriber codes, I used the one I mentioned above.

I've used **xy_pos** as the package name and **turtlebot_coordinates** as the node name.

I'm able to use `rosrun xy_pos turtlebot_coordinates`, it works fine.

However, when I try to use the node via a launch file, I've got the following error:

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [xy_pos/turtlebot_coordinates.cpp]: can't locate node [turtlebot_coordinates.cpp] in package [xy_pos].

The part of the launch file related to this node is:

`<node name="turtlebot_coordinates" pkg="xy_pos" type="turtlebot_coordinates.cpp" output="screen"> </node>`

It's not a problem with ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ( `roscd xy_pos` works fine)

I've tried the solution for [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/173543/node-not-found/) but it didn't work.

Does someone have any suggestion?

P.S: I don't know if this influences in something, but my **launch** file is inside an existing package. So while the **new** package is inside `catkin/src/`, the **launch** file is in a package inside `opt/ros/hydro/share/`. Is it a problem?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188869/cannot-locate-launch-node-of-type-+-can%27t-locate-node/) by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dido_yf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21158/dido_yf/) on 2014-12-18**:
hello, I have the same problem with you. Did you solve this problem? Could you tell me how?

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-12-18**:
Yes. Just remove the `.cpp` from the `type` argument as stated in ahendrix's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The node name you use in roslaunch should be the executable name; not the source file name.

Try it without the `.cpp`:

```
<node name="turtlebot_coordinates" pkg="xy_pos" type="turtlebot_coordinates" output="screen">
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-08-05**:
I was getting confused because for nodes written in python you need to include the source file name in the launch file. I didn't know it was different for nodes written in C++. Thanks ahendrix!

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2014-08-28**:
Yeah I think its a bit confusing too :S

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-29**:
The way I remember it is that the `pkg` and `type` arguments to the node tag are the same arguments I use with rosrun.

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2015-12-31**:
hell yeahhh! pkg and type should be the same argument! 45 min. trying to figure out this shit man!!! :D

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2018-02-21**:
Don't forget that you are actually executing yourscript.py for python nodes and running the executable (which probably is a name) for cpp nodes.